# No incoming transition animation for Activity

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to animate transition of activity. I need the activity to animate when it goes to backstack only i.e. call another activity.

I am using :

```
  overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

The arguments are resource integers

Is there any integer for no animation? I would like the integer value or Resource identifier so that there is no fade_in but only fade_out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like its zero . Lucky guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify 0 it won't do any animation, [docs for that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int))